# How do I turn off the double-down arrow on Vista menus?

Tags: windows-vista, start-menu

How do I turn off this guy here in the red circle.

[image]

- Endlessly hides stuff I want
- No obvious way to turn it off
- No obvious name to make this easy to do a web search for

It's just these two arrows that are the bane of my existence every time I click on a menu.

All I want is the FULL menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HOW TO: Show All Items on the Start Menu or Favorites Menu](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230596)

The solution is: Under the "Taskbar and Start Menu properties" dialog in the "Start Menu" tab you need to disable the "privacy" check-box for "recently opened programs"

Comment: THATS the freakin' answer man! Thanks, I've been wondering wtf controls this. Under the "Taskbar and Start Menu properties" dialog in the "start menu" tab you need to disable the "privacy" check-box for "recently opened programs"

Comment: Cool :) Glad it worked out.

Comment: @Incognito I edited in your solution to the actual answer, so people can read it more easily. That way we don't need to read through the comments :)